# Jquery remove added div without id

Tags: jquery

I have a form validation jquery I am adding a div before input element if the input element's value is empty. I want to remove the inserted div if a user gives value to the input element afterwards. I want to achieve this without adding id to the div.

```
    if($("#psalutation").val()==''){
      $("#psalutation").before('<div><center><font color="#C40404"><b>Please enter your last name below.</b></font></center></div>');
      $("#psalutation").focus();
      return false;
    }
```

thi is the html;

```
<div class="col-sm-7" style="padding-left:0px;">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-12 no-padding control-label">Your first name*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
      <input type="text" name="pfirstname" class="form-control" id="pfirstname" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show some HTML of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prev()` or `next()` to target the previous element or next element in respect to current selector:

```
$("#psalutation").prev("div:first").remove();
```

or

```
$("#psalutation").next("div:first").remove();
```

Refer: https://api.jquery.com/prev/  and https://api.jquery.com/next/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1073/

Click on the button to remove the div.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to remove only inserted div for that particular input

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan This will remove the inserted div before that input

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the validation divisions when you first run the validation function before any error insertion, besides, you don't need all the mess... You can use [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), its an excellent plugin for form validations and easily customizable.

```
$('input, select').prev('div').remove();

if($("#psalutation").val()==''){
      $("#psalutation").before('<div><center><font color="#C40404"><b>Please enter your last name below.</b></font></center></div>');
      $("#psalutation").focus();
      return false;
    }

if($("#pfirstname").val()==''){
      $("#pfirstname").before('<div><center><font color="#C40404"><b>Please enter your last name below.</b></font></center></div>');
      $("#pfirstname").focus();
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks this gives me idea how to add and remove warnings